# read line by line and compare with object

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to read line by line file and compare with value in a object that where passed to my function. Unfortunately I get information that object is undefined but when I checked it showed me correct data. This is code

```
 module.exports = function savefile(pathname, changesvalue){
   var counter = 0;
   var i = 0;
   var message = [];
   var test = changesvalue[i].seekrange; //here I have correct information

   var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(pathname)
   });
   lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
     if(counter == parseInt(changesvalue[i].seekrange)){   //here it showed that value is undefind
       var textadd = changesvalue[i].seektext.match(/([a-zA-Z-/]+)/g);
       message.push(' ' + textadd[0] + ' ' + changesvalue[i].seekvalue + textadd[1]);
       i++;
      }
      else{
       console.log(line);
      }
   counter++;
   });
   lineReader.on('end', function () {
     fs.writeFile('file_to_save_to', message, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
         }
     });
   }
 };
```

I don't now exactly why I get undefined? And how to processes this file in efficient way to read file, change some line and write to file?
Thank you for your help

Comment: How exactly do you call your _savefile_ function ? What is _seekrange_ ?

Comment: seekrange is the line number that is storage in object, that should be change

Comment: I don't get it. Could you provide an exemple of _changesvalue_ parameter ?

Comment: sure changesvalue is array of object {seekrange: 15, seekvalue: texttochange, seektext: anothertext}

Comment: about first question simply in post request I have line where I call savefile(path, req.body); and then I redirect to Get.